# remove object from screen through coordinates

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm working on a project where an object like a square should disappear when the coordinates are the same as another object. The first square should be placed on the second square, and the first square is smaller than the second square.

Here's the code:

```
    public function weg(e:Event):void
    {
    if (b.x < a.x && b.y < a.y && b.x + 60 > a.x + 50 && b.y + 60 > a.y + 50)
        {
            removeChild(a);
        }   
    }
```

The +50 comes from the width and heigth of square 1(a), and the +60 comes from the width and heigth of square 2(b) .

I can't seem to find the solution for the problem. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Only when the coordinates are *exactly* the same as another object? Why the `- 50`, then? What behavior does this code give you, and *exactly* what behavior are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

the coordinates of square1 cannot be larger than square1 (first if query) and on the other hand be smaller than square2 - 50 (second if query). So this will never be true.

If you want to check if the coordinates are the same just use:

```
public function check():void
{
    if (square1.x == square2.x && sqaure1.y == square2.y)
    {
        removeChild(square1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> an object like a square should disappear when the coordinates are the
>   same as another object.

If this is true you simply need:

```
if (square1.x == square2.x && square1.y == square2.y) {
    removeChild(square1);
}
```

However, the code you posted uses an offset of `-50`. You don't explain what you are trying to do with that value (it doesn't work because `x1 > x2 && x1 < x2 - 50` is impossible), so I'm only guessing, but perhaps you want to remove *overlapping* squares? You can do that a bunch of ways, here's one:

```
if (square1.getBounds(this).intersects(square2.getBounds(this))) {
    removeChild(square1);
}
```

Or perhaps you want to remove squares that are within a certain distance of each other. You could do that like this:

```
if (Point.distance(new Point(square1.x, square1.y), new Point(square2.x, square2.y)) < 50) {
    removeChild(square1);
}
```

Or perhaps you mean something else. Please update your question if so.